# Need help sorting using LINQ Lambda C#

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a List of Items: List items;
Each Item has a property Item #, LongID and InventoyBranchItem.
Each InventoyBranchItem has Item #, Item Quantity and BranchCode.

**Item**

```
Item #      Long ID         ItemInventoryLoc
123456      ANBCDDFD        1
999999      BBBBBBBB        1
777777      ATSDFDDF        1
```

**ItemInventoryLoc**

```
Item#       Quantity    BranchCode
123456      6           T1
999999      8           T3
777777      2           T2
```

I need to sort by BranchCode then by LongID. I am having trouble trying to do so with lambda.

```
List<Item> sortedList = items.OrderBy(x => x.ItemInventory....)
                .thenBy(x => x.LongID).ToList();
```

I don't know what syntax to use to get to the BranchCode.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I think you should really give us first of all how are your classes defined

Comment: I updated the description and added an image. The issue is x.InventoryBranchItem.BranchCode does not work. That is exactly where I want to go, but the syntax to get to it is incorrect.

Comment: Added image brings no value. It still unclear how you want sort them. What if item have multiple inventoryItems with different branch code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're sure an `Item` is always related o an `InventoryBrachItem`, then I guess you could do this to get the `BranchCode` in your `OrderBy`:

```
var sortedList = items.OrderBy(x => x.InventoryBrachItems.FirstOrDefault().BranchCode)
                      .ThenBy(x=> x.LongItemNumber);
```

But you need to explain more the logic you're pursuing to order your items, because it can be related with more than one `InventoryBranchItem`

Comment: I doubt that OP _don't know what syntax to use to get to the BranchCode_ if this is correct answer :)

Comment: I guess the same, but..let see what he/she says about that ;)

Comment: Yeah, that's not it. I wish :)

Comment: could you argue more in your question? It's not clear what you're trying to achieve. An example would be great

Comment: Downvoter could you explain why? Question was not very clear until now

Comment: That was it. It was .FirstOrDefault that did it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: `FirstOrDefault` just return first item. Maybe you need sort them before getting first item?

Answer (score 0):

I'm supposing that you have two lists: *Item* an *ItemInventoryLoc*

You should to join both lists and then sort the result

```
var qry = from items in itemsList join lockitems in ItemInventoryLocList
    on items.ItemNumber equals lockitems.ItemNumber
    orderby lockitems.BranchCode, items.LongItemNumber
    select new { 
        items.LongItemNumber, 
        lockitems.BranchCode, 
        lockitems.Quantity
     };
```

Working sample in [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vU44t0)